# Why is there a minimum amount for transfer (0.001 Ether)?

Tags: transactions, payments

Ethereum newbie here.
I tried transfering 0.0001ETH to one of my accounts for some testing. I realized there is a minimum limit of 0.001 ETH for transfers on the blockchain as shown by the error.

I was under the impression Ethereum and Bitcoin will enable Micropayments. How would this be possible with a minimum limit on the chain?

[image: Error on Coinbase.com]

Comment: I am trying to transfer my ETH from my blockchain wallet to a different system but can't see to f8nd how to do That..any suggestions please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't a limit on the blockchain, it's a limit on whatever service you're transferring from. You can even send 0 ETH when using a normal wallet. However, you will have to pay transaction fees.

Answer (score 3):

There is no minimum transaction amount on the Ethereum blockchain. You can send 0 ETH if you want.

The minimum you are seeing exists only inside the system of the website you are using. Once you get your Ether out of their system and into your own account, you can send as small a transaction as you want